# How to display xmls in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I have XML pages with some defined structure , now using flex I want to display the content of these pages. The purpose of using Flex is to give better look. 
If I can use something else which will provide a good UI to display then also its fine. 
Please suggest.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  You're using Flex to just display xml?! Seems overkill to me...

Answer (score 0):

you want to display the XML code??

read the xml file into a simple textarea and ready.

Damian

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `mx.controls.Tree` and fill its `dataProvider` with your XML. It's an old component, sometimes buggy when you want to tweak it, but it provides a neat display of a tree. In addition you could use a textarea to display the node currently selected.